# Select * From CSV File Where

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am wondering if there is a simple and intuitive way to do something like:

```
Select * From CSV File Where
```

I searched the web, but I couldn't find any SQL-type syntax that queries a CSV file.  In R, I can do this:

```
require(sqldf)
df <- read.csv.sql("C:\\your_path_here\\CSV1.csv", "select * from file where Name='Ryan'")
df
```

I am wondering if there is something similar in Python.

Comment: you can do that by loading the csv into a dataframe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the CSV into a `pandas` `DataFrame` and then you can use [`pandasql`](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql) to perform SQL queries on your data

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv')
df1 = ps.sqldf('select * from df where x>=10', locals())
```

Comment: Thanks so much aydow.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks to everyone else.  Everything was helpful, and I saved all these solutions to my personal library for future reference.